# Extracting numbers from a 32-bit integer

Tags: bit

I'm trying to solve a riddle in a programming test.

Disclaimer: It's a test for a job, but I'm not looking for an answer. I'm just looking for an understanding of how to do this. The test requires that I come up with a set of solutions to a set of problems within 2 weeks, and it doesn't state a requirement that I arrive at the solutions in isolation.

So, the problem:

I have a 32-bit number with the bits arranged like this:

```
siiiiiii iiiiiiii ifffffff ffffffff
```

Where:

- s is the sign bit (1 == negative)
- i is 16 integer bits
- f is 15 fraction bits

The assignment is to write something that decodes a 32-bit integer into a floating-point number. Given the following inputs, it should produce the following outputs:

```
input            output

0x00008000   1.0
0x80008000  -1.0
0x00010000   2.0
0x80014000  -2.5
0x000191eb  3.14
0x00327eb8    100.99
```

I'm having no trouble getting the sign bit or the integer part of the number. I get the sign bit like this:

```
boolean signed = ((value & (1 << 31)) != 0);
```

I get the integer and fraction parts like this:

```
int wholePart = ((value & 0x0FFFFFFF) >> 15);

int fractionPart = ((value & 0x0000FFFF >> 1));
```

The part I'm having an issue with is getting the number in the last 15 bits to match the expected values. 
Instead of 3.14, I get 3.4587, etc.

If someone could give me a hint about what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it. More than anything else, the fact that I haven't figured this out after hours of messing with it is kind of driving me nuts. :-)

Comment: You have a problem with the wholePart mask that the test data won't reveal.  The doubled parentheses in the fractionPart expression don't match the parentheses in the wholePart expression; but I don't see a reason to shift the fractionPart anyway.  The fractionPart mask is wrong, too.

Answer (score 4):

Company's inputs aren't wrong.  The fractional bits don't represent the the literal digits right of the decimal point, they represent the *fractional* part.  Don't know how else to say it without giving it away.  Would it be too big a hint to say there is a divide involved?

Comment: To 5 decimal places, that's correct (and the given values print accurately at 5 decimal places as above with 3 extra zeroes).  A 15-bit fraction gives approximately 0.00003 (1 / 32K) per count, so 4 or 5 decimal places are reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

A few things...

Why not get the fractional part as

```
int fractionPart = value & 0x00007FFF;  // i.e. no shifting needed...
```

Similarly, no shifting needed for the sign

```
boolean signed = ((value & (0x80000000) != 0);  // signed is true when negative
```

See Ryan's response for the effective use of the *fractional part*, i.e. not taking this literally as the digit values for the decimal part but rather... some' involving a fraction...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what you're anding the fraction part with prior to the shift.

Answer (score 0):

```
int wholePart = ((value & 0x7FFFFFFF) >> 15);

int fractionPart = (value & 0x00007FFF);
```

Key your bit-mask into Calculator in Binary mode and then flip it to Hex...

Answer (score 0):

Shift Right 31 gives you the signed bit 1=Neg 0=Pos

```
BEFORE siiiiiii iiiiiiii ifffffff ffffffff
SHR 31 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000000s
```

Shift Left 1 followed by Shift Right 16 gives you the Integer bits

```
BEFORE siiiiiii iiiiiiii ifffffff ffffffff
SHL 1  iiiiiiii iiiiiiii ffffffff fffffff0
SHR 16 00000000 00000000 iiiiiiii iiiiiiii
```

Shift Left 17 followed by Shift Right 15 gives for the Faction bits

```
BEFORE siiiiiii iiiiiiii ifffffff ffffffff
SHL 17 ffffffff fffffff0 00000000 00000000
SHR 16 00000000 00000000 0fffffff ffffffff
```